# Symfony2 Sonata Admin Bundle Social Share functionality

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3

i want to implement a social share functionality in sonata admin bundle Symfony2. Whenever a editor created an article and published it that will automatically  share on facebook or twitter.

Just want to know that is any bundle available which has social share functionality???

Last option 
if bundle is  not available then i have to made my own bundle

Answer (score 1):

There is no social network API implementation in the Sonata suite at the moment, beside referencing through the SonataSeoBundle (http://sonata-project.org/bundles/seo/master/doc/reference/installation.html).

We are interested in adding this feature in the Sonata bundles, feel free to discuss it with us by creating an issue on github.

Answer (score 1):

Only for Sonata Admin No. specific bundle.
You can try this in your back-end :

- [Facebook Bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle)
- [Twitter Bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSTwitterBundle)

Or

try this Bundle :
https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle

Maybe this is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is here an article, maybe it helps: http://obtao.com/blog/2012/11/create-a-social-buttons-bar-for-facebook-twitter-and-google-with-symfony2/